# Touch ID build error on Xcode6-beta5 running on real device iphone5s

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, touch-id

I am using Xcode6-beta5 to integrate touch ID authentication into my own application.Running on real device iphone5s(iOS8-beta5), using the following code.
Already #import .

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"use touch id to unlock app";

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
     [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
               localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                         reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                            if (success) {
                               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"pass auth" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK button") otherButtonTitles:nil];

                               [alert show];
                               [alert release];

                               // User authenticated successfully, take appropriate action
                            } else {
                               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"fail" message:@"fail auth" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK button") otherButtonTitles:nil];

                               [alert show];
                               [alert release];
                               // User did not authenticate successfully, look at error and take appropriate action
                            }
                         }];
  } else {
     // Could not evaluate policy; look at authError and present an appropriate message to user
  }
```

But when I compile and run it shows build failed:

*Ld build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HWC normal armv7
    cd /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HWC.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/HWC-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt -dead_strip -all_load ../../../Pioneer/MOClients/iPhone/build/Debug-iphoneos/libMO.a ../../../Pioneer/Robie/Device/iPhone/Datavault/build/Debug-iphoneos/libDatavault.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/afaria/libs/Debug-iphoneos/libAfariaSLL.a ../../../TPTools/PhoneGap/iOS/CordovaLib/build/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/ClientUtil/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libsupClientUtil.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/ClientUtil/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libSUPSupportability.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/ClientUtil/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libPerformanceLib.a ../../../Pioneer/Robie/Device/iPhone/Widgets/HWCLib/build/Debug-iphoneos/libHWC.a ../../../TPTools/OpenSSL/iOS/Debug-iphoneos/libcrypto.a -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -lstdc++.6.0.9 -framework CoreTelephony -lz.1.2.5 -lstdc++ -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework UIKit -licucore.A -framework AddressBook -framework CoreMedia -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HWC_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HWC*

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LAContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HWCAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HWC normal arm64
    cd /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HWC.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/HWC-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -dead_strip -all_load ../../../Pioneer/MOClients/iPhone/build/Debug-iphoneos/libMO.a ../../../Pioneer/Robie/Device/iPhone/Datavault/build/Debug-iphoneos/libDatavault.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/afaria/libs/Debug-iphoneos/libAfariaSLL.a ../../../TPTools/PhoneGap/iOS/CordovaLib/build/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/ClientUtil/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libsupClientUtil.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/ClientUtil/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libSUPSupportability.a ../../../TPTools/iOS/ClientUtil/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libPerformanceLib.a ../../../Pioneer/Robie/Device/iPhone/Widgets/HWCLib/build/Debug-iphoneos/libHWC.a ../../../TPTools/OpenSSL/iOS/Debug-iphoneos/libcrypto.a -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -lstdc++.6.0.9 -framework CoreTelephony -lz.1.2.5 -lstdc++ -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework UIKit -licucore.A -framework AddressBook -framework CoreMedia -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HWC_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/i307466/Downloads/OneBridge/trunk/Apps/iPhone/WorkFlow/build/HWC.build/Debug-iphoneos/HWC.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HWC

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LAContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HWCAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I've found my problem, most of time when you use a new framework, please add new lib to your project.pbxproj.
I was just forgotting to add LocalAuthentication.framework to my project.pbxproj.
In xcode, navigate to General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries->+ (select the framework or lib you want to add)

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't appear that you're linking LocalAuthentication.framework. Add it to your app's target in Xcode (General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries->+->LocalAuthentication.framework).